# Can this question linked from Software Engineering be undeleted?

Tags: support, vote-to-undelete

I was studying about why using boolean as parameters is bad, and one of comments on Software Engineering:

```
Also see stackoverflow.com/questions/1240739/… and stackoverflow.com/questions/6107221/… – Christoffer Hammarström May 10 '12 at 14:18
```

(link: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/147977/is-it-wrong-to-use-a-boolean-parameter-to-determine-behavior?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment280173_147977)

contains the link of this question:

*https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240739/boolean-parameters-do-they-smell*

But this question was deleted currently, and I would like to know the context of the question since it seems to contain useful information (according to the score and reply of that comment). Can this question be undeleted?

Comment: [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwLkE.png)

Comment: _"Code smell"_ is often a matter of opinion. That's probably why the question was deleted.

Comment: Short answer, no. This question is primary opinion based so this don't fit in stack overflow.

Comment: The question is followed by a 19 answers that basically say: *Don't be Stupid*.

Comment: Would make more sense to delete that comment on SoftwareEngineering if the link has gone stale

Comment: By the way, here's the contents of that question: https://imgur.com/a/O4f8K

Comment: What have you got against booleans?  Some data types get an undeserved bad press.   I think it's type discrimination at its worst.  :)

Comment: @MartinJames some people are still unwilling to adapt their programs to the concept of "lower ground boolean types" (LGBT).

Answer (score 3):

The question was actually deleted back in 2015...

[image: Deleted by community members (quite a lot of them) on October 6, 2015]

...so I'm reluctant to call this "recent".

That said I agree with the deletion.  The big problem is that this will encourage and invite yet *more* opinionated answers, and opinions aren't what we're looking for.

As a sampling:

> Do not use Booleans unless you are absolutely sure there will never be a need for more than two values.
>
> ---
>
> The problem (in this particular example) is not with the boolean parameter itself, but with the name of the method that contains it
>
> ---
>
> I'd say pretty much the same thing you'd think if you saw DoSomething(5). If you aren't sure what the API of a given function is, then it's best to look at the function definition. There's nothing wrong with a boolean parameter any more than there's something wrong with a parameter of any other type. If the caller doesn't know the API, no amount of data type gymnastics will help that.

All of these answers scored above 10, and all of them are *opinions*.  There's no concrete *fact* here.

I'm not in favor of undeleting it.  It's not a good question as is for the site, and no amount of editing will *discourage* opinions from this hotly contentious practice.

Why not just flag the comment for deletion?  It's run its course.